# file.edit() in R works for some text files but not others

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `file.edit()` to open files from a script in R. Following the answer to this question, i.e.:

`file.edit("example-file.txt")`

However, this only seems to work for kinds of text files (with certain extensions). For example, the following four files can all be opened in a text file, however only the first two open in the (R Studio) file editor:

```
> list.files()
[1] "d.dat"                "i.inp"                "Mplus Run Models.log" "README.md"           
# works
> file.edit("README.md") 
# works
> file.edit("Mplus Run Models.log")
# does not work
> file.edit("d.dat")
# does not work
> file.edit("i.inp")
```

Should `file.edit()` work for files with `.dat` or `.inp` extensions - and if so, how?

Comment: define "does not work," an error, non-responsive? I would guess this depends on your os and default text editor also

Comment: non-responsive. Nothing loads but no message or warning or error is returned.

Comment: This seems to be an RStudio specific issue. Within RStudio, if you use `utils::file.edit()` an editor window does open up, regardless of the file extension.

Comment: Seems likely that you do not have the correct path for the names that bring up a blank edit window.